# How can I use lodash reject to reject multiple possible properties of the same key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am using [lodash reject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reject) in order to reject multiple possible properties of an array of objects.

```
const operatingCountries = reject(operating_countries, ['country', null]);
```

Or

```
const operatingCountries = reject(operating_countries, ['country', ""]);
```

Or

```
const operatingCountries = reject(operating_countries, ['country', false]);
```

So and I will need to do something like:

```
const operatingCountries = reject(operating_countries, ['country', null || 'country', ""]);
```

So I want to test the `country` property to check if it comes with a string in it. Not an empty string. I need it to come with a value which is a string, I don't need any `false`, `null`, `""`, etc...

So what options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter()` or lodash filter, and return the value:

```js
const operating_countries = [{ country: '' }, { country: 'cats' }, { country: null }]

const result = operating_countries.filter(({ country }) => country)

console.log(result)
```

Or with lodash:

```js
const operating_countries = [{ country: '' }, { country: 'cats' }, { country: null }]

const result = _.filter(operating_countries, 'country')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
const operatingCountries = reject(operating_countries, 'country')
```

And it'll return all the records that have nulls, blanks, undefined's, etc.. for the `country` property. That's because `country` will evaluate to `false` for those cases.

If you want to remove the records with bad countries, and only keep the good ones, then you can use a plain javascript filter:

```
const operatingCountries = operating_countries.filter(({country}) => country)
```

This works because strings that have more than one character are considered `true`.

Comment: But I need to ignore every falsy value. All I want are the string values.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it's falsy:

```
const operatingCountries = reject(operating_countries, ([e, f]) => f));
```

Comment: What is that `([e, f]) => f`? Can you explain. I don't get it.

Comment: The `([e, f]) => f` returns the value of the second item in each array in `operating_countries`. If it's `true` exclude it, if it's `false` keep it.

Comment: Error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in your own function to define how it should reject. Here I have defined a arrow function which extracts the `country` (using [destructuing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) from each object and rejects it if it is "falsey":

```
const operatingCountries = reject(operating_countries, ({country}) => !country);
console.log(operatingCountries);
```